# Tensorboard Cannot find .runfiles directory error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I installed tensorboard via pip and when I try to execute `tensorboard --logdir= Graph/`  I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pawan/.local/bin/tensorboard", line 152, in <module>
    Main()
  File "/home/pawan/.local/bin/tensorboard", line 102, in Main
    module_space = FindModuleSpace()
  File "/home/pawan/.local/bin/tensorboard", line 83, in FindModuleSpace
    sys.argv[0])
    AssertionError: Cannot find .runfiles directory for /home/pawan/.local/bin/tensorboard
```

I do `which tensorboard` and get the following

```
/home/pawan/.local/bin/tensorboard
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

It seems they didn't consider that someone would be pip-installing TensorBoard in a user directory. Below is my *hack* to get it to work:

In the `~/.local/bin/tensorboard` script, there's a section that looks like this:

```
def FindModuleSpace():
  # Follow symlinks, looking for my module space
  stub_filename = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
  while True:
    # Found it?
    module_space = stub_filename + '.runfiles'
    if os.path.isdir(module_space):
      break
    for mod in site.getsitepackages():
      module_space = mod + '/tensorboard/tensorboard' + '.runfiles'
      if os.path.isdir(module_space):
        return module_space
```

(just above the assertion with the "Cannot find .runfiles directory" error).

The directory it's looking for is

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles
```

which you can discover by running `find ~/.local -name '*runfiles*'`.

I simply added it to the `for` loop over directories and all is well:

```
    for mod in site.getsitepackages() + [os.path.expanduser("~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")]
```

This is a *hack* because:

- I explicitly said `python2.7`, which might not be the version of Python you're using. Correct it for your case.
- The use of forward slashes won't work on Windows; a chain of `os.path.join` would be better.
- This issue really should be communicated back to the TensorBoard developers. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

We have to search for the tensorboard folder and run the tensorboard file there.

Search for the tensorflow folder and do the following(My tensorflow folder was there in ~/ itself):

```
cd ~/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorboard
```

Now run:

```
python tensorboard --logdir=(the location of your logs path)
```